# PyInstaller fatal error: 'zmq.h' file not found

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller

On MacOS running pyinstaller I get the following trace:

```
35 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.6
35 INFO: Python: 3.7.7
41 INFO: Platform: Darwin-16.7.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
44 INFO: UPX is not available.

[...]

55950 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-zmq.py"...
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zmq/backend/cffi/__pycache__/_cffi_ext.c:216:10: fatal error: 'zmq.h' file not found
#include <zmq.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
57608 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-gevent.py"...
57732 INFO: Determining a mapping of distributions to packages...
83010 WARNING: Unable to find package for requirement greenlet from package gevent.

[...]

83742 WARNING: library user32 required via ctypes not found
83832 WARNING: library setupapi required via ctypes not found
83833 WARNING: library Advapi32 required via ctypes not found

[...]

125669 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

This does not block the build process, but when I run the output program I get

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Anyone else experienced this issue?

Comment: How did you install pyinstaller and what version of Python are you running? This traceback doesn't seam complete or is it?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Python 3.7.7 I'll edit question with more info

Comment: And what library are you trying to install? :) zmg is a dependency I guess :) This feels like a zmg bug if anything

Comment: @Torxed thanks for your comments, I found a way to make the app work  even if the fatal error didn't go away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found very useful to search in the **warnings file generated by PyInstaller**

In the command output there's a line

```
85263 INFO: Warnings written to /path/to/warn-file.txt
```

If I search for zmq the first warning is a top-level import

```
missing module named multiprocessing.Process - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), zmq.ssh.tunnel (top-level)
```

That gave me 2 hints:

- **multiprocessing** was involved in a lot of warnings shown only in that file
- searching through the file a lot of warnings where related to **PyQt5** which is imported in my application

I searched for multiprocessing and pyqt imports and removed two unused imports:

```
from PyQt5.uic import compileUiDir
from multiprocessing import Pool as ThreadPool
```

This doesn't remove that strange `zmq.h` missing header fatal error but it makes the application run correctly after the build.

Sharing my solution here, maybe it can be useful for others...